# How to prevent ReadDirectoryChangesW from returning spurious Modified events when iterating directory

Tags: c++, winapi, readdirectorychangesw

I use `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` to detect changes made to a directory tree. When testing my implementation, I found that iterating over a just created directory tree causes `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` to return spurious Modified events.

- Create a directory tree
- Start watching the tree with `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`
- Iterate over the directory tree

Expected: `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` reports no changes.

Actual: `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` reports Modified changes.

I used the following code to reproduce this issue:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace
{
    HANDLE createHandle(std::filesystem::path const& directory) {
        std::wstring path = directory.wstring();
        LPCWSTR dirPath = static_cast<LPCWSTR>(path.c_str());
        HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(
            dirPath,
            FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            NULL);
        return handle;
    }

    class DirectoryWatcher
    {
    private:
        std::filesystem::path _rootDir;

        HANDLE _dirHandle;
        DWORD _bufferSizeInBytes;
        std::unique_ptr<DWORD> _buffer;
        OVERLAPPED _overlapped;

        std::mutex _mutex;
        std::condition_variable _cond;
        bool _running;
        std::atomic<bool> _stop;
        std::unique_ptr<std::thread> _watcher;

    public:
        DirectoryWatcher(std::filesystem::path const& directory)
            : _rootDir(directory)
            , _dirHandle(createHandle(_rootDir))
            , _bufferSizeInBytes(32 * 1024)
            , _buffer(new DWORD[_bufferSizeInBytes / sizeof(DWORD)])
            , _running(false)
            , _stop(false)
        {
            if (_dirHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw std::runtime_error("dir handle creation failed");
            memset(&_overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
            _overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL);
            if (_overlapped.hEvent == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw std::runtime_error("event handle creation failed");
            _watcher = std::make_unique<std::thread>(&DirectoryWatcher::run, this);

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            while (!_running) _cond.wait(lock);
        }

        ~DirectoryWatcher() {
            _stop = true;
            SetEvent(_overlapped.hEvent); // to wakeup WaitForSingleObject
            _watcher->join();
            CancelIo(_dirHandle);
            CloseHandle(_overlapped.hEvent);
            CloseHandle(_dirHandle);
        }

    private:
        void queueReadChangeRequest() {
            BOOL success = ReadDirectoryChangesW(
                _dirHandle, _buffer.get(), _bufferSizeInBytes, TRUE,
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
                NULL, &_overlapped, NULL);
            if (!success) throw std::runtime_error("ReadDirectoryChangesW failed");
        }

        void run() {
            const DWORD waitTimeoutInMs = 100;
            queueReadChangeRequest();
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
                _running = true;
                _cond.notify_one();
            }
            while (!_stop) {
                DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(_overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE);
                if (!_stop && result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
                    DWORD bytesTransferred;
                    GetOverlappedResult(_dirHandle, &_overlapped, &bytesTransferred, FALSE);
                    if (bytesTransferred == 0) {
                        std::cout << "Overflow" << std::endl;
                    } else {
                        std::size_t offset = 0;
                        PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION info;
                        do
                        {
                            info = reinterpret_cast<PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION>(&_buffer.get()[offset]);
                            offset += info->NextEntryOffset;
                            std::wstring fileNameStr(info->FileName, info->FileNameLength / sizeof(wchar_t));
                            std::filesystem::path fileName(_rootDir / fileNameStr);
                            if (info->Action == FILE_ACTION_ADDED) {
                                std::cout << "Added " << fileName << std::endl;
                            } else if (info->Action == FILE_ACTION_REMOVED) {
                                std::cout << "Removed " << fileName << std::endl;
                            } else if (info->Action == FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED) {
                                std::cout << "Modified " << fileName << std::endl;
                            } else if (info->Action == FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME) {
                                std::cout << "Renamed old name " << fileName << std::endl;
                            } else if (info->Action == FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME) {
                                std::cout << "Renamed new name " << fileName << std::endl;
                            }
                        } while (info->NextEntryOffset != 0);
                    }
                    queueReadChangeRequest();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    void iterateDirectory(std::filesystem::path const& dir)
    {
        for (auto const& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
            if (entry.is_directory()) {
                std::filesystem::path s3(dir / entry.path());
                for (auto const& subentry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(dir)) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string tmpDir(std::tmpnam(nullptr));
    std::filesystem::path rootDir(std::string(tmpDir + "_spuriousEvents"));
    std::filesystem::path subDir0(rootDir / "subDir0");
    std::filesystem::path subDir00(subDir0 / "subDir00");
    std::filesystem::create_directory(rootDir);
    std::filesystem::create_directory(subDir0);
    std::filesystem::create_directory(subDir00);
    std::cout << "Created directory " << rootDir.string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Created directory " << subDir0.string() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Created directory " << subDir00.string() << std::endl;

    DirectoryWatcher watcher(rootDir);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Started watching directory tree " << rootDir.string() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Unexpected event during first directory iteration" << std::endl;
    iterateDirectory(subDir0);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "No unexpected event during subsequent directory iterations" << std::endl;
    iterateDirectory(subDir0);
    iterateDirectory(subDir0);

    char input = '\0';
    while (input == '\0') std::cin >> input;
}
```

Comment: FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE is probably your nemesis.  It is a file property that is updated lazily to amortize its cost.  When you iterate the directory it can no longer be delayed.  Or in other words, the directory entry for the file did in fact get modified, you just didn't get a notification for it yet.

Comment: This is indeed the problem: the spurious event no longer reproduces when I flush the cache (using sysinternals sync.exe) after the directory tree creation and before starting the watcher. Now the question changes to: what to do when my application relies on timely notification of file and directory changes?

Comment: @PeterJaspers: I don't know why you believe the behavior Hans described is not a timely notification.  The updates were delayed when no one was watching.  When your program started watching, the OS stopped being lazy.  The real test would be watching during both the directory creation and iteration, and seeing whether you get the events during creation (timely) or delayed until iteration.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I find it not timely because the OS stopped being lazy when I started iterating the directory tree, NOT when I started watching. I also ran the 'real test'. I do get sufficient events to figure out what has happened but not all the events that I expect. E.g. when adding a file I do get a FileAdded event but not a DirectoryModified event. Only after iterating the modified directory I get the DirectoryModified event.